# MySQL installation on Ubuntu 20.04 password error when using mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a password issue when installing MySQL in Ubuntu on WSL2.
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64).

I have done the following:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server

# it was successfully installed. Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

sudo service mysql start

sudo mysql_secure_installation

# here I had same sort of a problem described in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

# so I had to do

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'my_password!123';

# after that, I was able to set a password as MEDIUM following this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04
```

However, then I could not log back in with 'my_password!123'.

```
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo mysql
[sudo] password for bluetail14:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

also got

```
bluetail@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I started and stopped the mysql server, closed Ubuntu and opened it again, but I'm stuck.
Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Is there a MySQL instance running - `ps -e | grep mysqld`? If not, check the error log /var/log/mysql/error.log. Are you able to connect if you specify the local loop back address for the host?

Comment: yes, it is running. I got 
23045 ?        00:00:00 mysqld_safe
23109 ?        00:00:03 mysqld

Comment: Have you tried `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`?

Comment: solved it eventually. sudo mysql -u root -p
[sudo] password for bluetail:  <---- my sudo user password
Enter password: <---- my root password